# SEVERE: Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot project but I get the following error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void destroy()' of interface javax.servlet.Filter.
```

I had to exclude all the `logback-classic` because I was getting the following error

```
LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/ootero/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.7/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tecnositaf.progetto_kafka_okd</groupId>
    <artifactId>alert_consumer_processor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>alert_consumer_processor</name>
    <description>Demo project for kafka consumer processor</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Have you got any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Why do you exclude `logback-classic`, any particular reason? Also, the problem is possibly with one of your filters...

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  Any chance you figured this out?

Comment: @GarySharpe the way I solved it was not by excluding the dependencies in my project but by compiling my project with the command mvn clean install from the spring boot terminal and then executing the generated .jar in the target folder with java -jar jarname.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was **not** by excluding the dependencies in my project but **by changing the way I compile** my project.

Now I use the command `mvn clean install` from the intellij command line for compiling.
For executing I move in the `target` directory so that I can execute the generated `.jar` in the this folder with `java -jar jarname.jar` from the intellij command line.